# Android - ClipDrawable, ScaleDrawable, how does it work?

Tags: android, graphics, drawable, surfaceview

I'm having quite a problem here and I hope for someone here to able to help me. let's go.

Let's say, I have quite a big image ( 1500x2000 ), i load it as a drawable, fine so far. Now I have a SurfaceView and I want to draw a certain region ( lets say the top-left-most region ) onto a canvas, in a non-scaled version. I thought using ClipDrawable would be just the right thing to use, but actually, I can't get it to do what I want to. It just displays a scaled-down image with the clip applied.

So basically my question is: how to draw a non-scaled drawable onto a surface, and how to clip that drawable?

any help appreciated, thank you :-)

Comment: Alright, I'm no using the Modelview transformations provided by the Canvas object. Works fine.

Comment: Can I see the code for how you got this working?

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I couldn't find it right now.. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clip a drawable simply set the appropriate clip region on the Canvas prior to drawing the drawable. Don't forget to save()/restore() the Canvas!

Comment: thats the way i'm going now. took some time to figure it out, well now it works. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these in XML Drawable.

Check this doc for more usage for `clip` and `scale` label:
http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html

Comment: Whats with the link, why not link to the official documentation instead of just a screen scrapped lo-fi version?